# Short film with crashed spaceship and non-English narrator

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I vaguely remember watching a short film that was posted on Facebook a couple of months ago (it was around 10mins long). I think the film is narrated in French (definitely not English) and it starts off with a crashed spaceship on a barren alien planet. There is only one survivor who has ended up quite a distance away from his ship (he is wearing a full white space suit with helmet so you don't see his face). He is running out of oxygen so he starts to run to find his ship, but he is being pursued by an Prometheus-esque alien (that you don't see for a while). Whilst he is running, the narrator describes the man's situation and what might be going through his head. The narrator then says "no, no, no. You're not in a stranded on a planet, you are..." and then it cuts to another scene/situation based "reality."

Again, the narrator goes through the scene, but then say "no, no, no..." and it then cuts to another different scene/situation. There are about 4 or 5 different stories which the film then cuts in-between as each slowly develops.

From what I can remember, the astronaut passes out at one point and the alien burrows into his space suit. When he wakes up, he starts to run again and the narrator describes how "you're trying to ignore the thing crawling up your leg" or something like that.

Does it ring any bells with anyone?!?! I've been racking my brain trying to find it online, but my search keeps bringing up "Grounded" and "Seed," which it isn't. The person/group/sponsored Facebook post did comment on how similar the planet and the alien was to Prometheus.

Comment: CG or live-action?

Comment: Live action (apart from the alien)

Answer (score 11):

You're thinking of [*Voice Over*](https://www.shortoftheweek.com/2013/03/25/voice-over/),  which is narrated in French.

> Already a festival and online hit, it's quite likely you've already heard about Voice Over, but on the off chance that you haven't, you're in for a real treat. A short film on an epic scale, its main feature is the titular voiceover. The clearly agitated narrator informs you that the astronaut on the screen is you. And you're in trouble. You see, you've crash-landed and your pressurized suit will only keep you alive for a limited amount of time. But before your air runs out, you're whisked away to a totally different scenario. And then, with a similar race against time counting down, it happens again. Each scenario is gorgeously shot, making for three mini-action movies in one. But it's the denouement that will have you cheering. Writer Luiso Berdejo is much more famous for his involvement with the horror films REC and REC 3: Genesis but here he is able to cover the sweep from epic to intimate in 10 short minutes.

### Full film with subtitles